# Change summarize() calculation for a specific group

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following dummy dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
                                     1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L), 
                                   .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                                              "5", "6", "Total"), class = "factor"), 
                     y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
                                     2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
                                   .Label = c("7", "8", "9", "Total"), class = "factor"), 
                     z = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
                                     1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
                                   .Label = c("10", "11"), class = "factor"), 
                     count = c(56, 89, 12, 119, 3, 2, 71, 
                               210, 22, 64, 53, 0, 136, 11, 211, 75), 
                     date = structure(c(17866, 
                                        17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17866, 17501, 17501, 
                                        17501, 17501, 17501, 17501, 17501, 17501), class = "Date")), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -16L), 
                .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "count", "date")) %>%
  filter(count != 0)

> df
       x     y  z count       date
1      1     7 10    56 2018-12-01
2      2     7 11    89 2018-12-01
3      3     8 10    12 2018-12-01
4      4     8 11   119 2018-12-01
5      5     9 10     3 2018-12-01
6      6     9 11     2 2018-12-01
7  Total Total 10    71 2018-12-01
8  Total Total 11   210 2018-12-01
9      1     7 10    22 2017-12-01
10     2     7 11    64 2017-12-01
11     3     8 10    53 2017-12-01
12     5     9 10   136 2017-12-01
13     6     9 11    11 2017-12-01
14 Total Total 10   211 2017-12-01
15 Total Total 11    75 2017-12-01
```

I am interested in computing year-over-year percent changes with a slight modification.

Here's the **unmodified** version (what I **don't** want, but is close):

```
df_yoy <- df %>%
  group_by(x, y, z) %>%
  summarize(YoY = count[date == max(date)]/count[date == min(date)] - 1) %>%
  as.data.frame()

> df_yoy
      x     y  z        YoY
1     1     7 10  1.5454545
2     2     7 11  0.3906250
3     3     8 10 -0.7735849
4     4     8 11  0.0000000
5     5     9 10 -0.9779412
6     6     9 11 -0.8181818
7 Total Total 10 -0.6635071
8 Total Total 11  1.8000000 <-- obtained by doing 210/75-1
```

Notice how I'm specifically calling out the last row. Here are the requirements of what I want:

1. The `count` values need to remain the same.
2. The `count` when `x == 4 & y == 8 & z == 11` was not measured on `2017-12-01`. Thus, **when computing the YoY percent change for the *total rows*, the counts when `x == 4 & y == 8 & z == 11` need to be excluded in the numerator `count[date == max(date)]`**.

Thus, **here is the output I'm looking for**:

```
> df_yoy
      x     y  z        YoY
1     1     7 10  1.5454545
2     2     7 11  0.3906250
3     3     8 10 -0.7735849
4     4     8 11  0.0000000
5     5     9 10 -0.9779412
6     6     9 11 -0.8181818
7 Total Total 10 -0.6635071
8 Total Total 11  0.2133333 <-- obtained by doing (210-119)/75-1
```

Notice that the subtraction of `119` from `210` is the `count` value when `x == 4 & y == 8 & z == 11`.

Is there a way to modify `summarize()` to perform this change? I have already tried playing around with `ifelse()` and `case_when()`, but with no success.

Comment: Typically when something is not measured, it is coded as NA (so you'd get NA instead of Inf in your result). Any reason to use 0 for it here?

Comment: @Frank Actually... now that I'm looking at my actual data set, the row where I have a `0` is actually omitted. Let me change this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be reached by `ungroup` and regroup to do transformation using `dplyr`.

**Note:** The solution can be written in a concise form but I choose to write in a bit detailed way so that it would be easier for OP/readers to understand logic.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(count = ifelse(count==0, NA, count)) %>%
  group_by(x, y, z) %>%
  summarize(YoYNume = count[date == max(date)], YoYDeno = count[date == min(date)]) %>%
  group_by(z) %>%
  mutate(valueToDiscard = sum(ifelse(is.na(YoYDeno),YoYNume,0))) %>%
  mutate(YoYNume = ifelse(x=="Total", YoYNume - valueToDiscard, valueToDiscard)) %>%
  group_by(x,y,z) %>%
  summarise(YoY = YoYNume/YoYDeno - 1) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#       x     y  z        YoY
# 1     1     7 10 -1.0000000
# 2     2     7 11  0.8593750
# 3     3     8 10 -1.0000000
# 4     4     8 11         NA
# 5     5     9 10 -1.0000000
# 6     6     9 11  9.8181818
# 7 Total Total 10 -0.6635071
# 8 Total Total 11  0.2133333
```